# How to add NERDTree to your .vimrc

Tags: vim, nerdtree

How do I add NERDTree to my .vimrc?

Comment: I updated my answer. I'm not sure you can add it to your .vimrc to do what you want, but I know you can run vim from the command line in a way that opens up NERDTree automatically. Take a look :)

Answer (score 214, accepted):

Okay, the previous version was a bit terse, but the answer you're looking for is to add the line below into your `~/.vimrc` file.  It tells Vim that you want to setup a command to run when Vim starts, but since it depends on various plugins to be loaded, you don't want to run it until all initialization is finished:

```
autocmd VimEnter * NERDTree
```

If, however, you're annoyed by the fact that the cursor always starts in the NERDTree window, you can add a second autocommand that will move the cursor into the main window:

```
autocmd VimEnter * NERDTree
autocmd VimEnter * wincmd p
```

Comment: I dont know why but this does not work for me. I have to call :NERDTreeToggle inside vim to show nerdtree anyway

Comment: If you're using a script like vimpager you should move these lines to your `/.vim/after/plugin/NERD_tree.vim` script, so that it doesn't try to execute with plugins turned off.

Comment: You don't need two separate autocmd's: `autocmd VimEnter * NERDTree | wincmd p`

Comment: could I simply specify the actual path I want to start in? - Yup works with a folder (just no slash in the end)

Comment: I prefer to do the following:

    `autocmd VimEnter * NERDTree` and then
    `autocmd VimEnter * if argc() | wincmd p | endif`.

That way, the cursor is on NERDTree if I haven't opened a specific file, but if I did pick a file it starts in the main window.

Comment: 'm trying to setup up NERDTree with neovim 0.4.4 (release) but it's not working. I copied the autocmd code snippets from the projects github page.

Answer (score 24):

I like to see NERDTree only when I start vim without file arguments, so I added this to my .vimrc:

```
autocmd VimEnter * if !argc() | NERDTree | endif
```

Answer (score 20):

Are you on a Windows or unix-y system?

If you're on a unix-y system you put plugins in `~/.vim/plugin`. Here's what my plugin directory looks like:

```
$ ls ~/.vim/plugin
NERD_tree.vim  scratch.vim  scratchfind.vim
```

After that it starts working right away. Try running vim like this:

```
$ vim .
```

It should open the current directory in the NERD tree view.

If you're on Windows you put plugins here: `C:\Program Files\Vim\vim70\plugin`

---

To get NERDTree to load automatically when you start up vim, run it like this from the command line:

```
$ vim -c "NERDTree" some_file.txt
```

You can set an alias for this in your `.bashrc`:

```
alias vimt='vim -c "NERDTree" $1'
```

Now whenever you run `vimt` (instead of `vim`) you'll also open up NERDTree on the left side of the window.

You could also add a shortcut key to start NERDTree in your `.vimrc` this way:

```
function OpenNERDTree()
  execute ":NERDTree"
endfunction
command -nargs=0 OpenNERDTree :call OpenNERDTree()

nmap <ESC>t :OpenNERDTree<CR>
```

Now when you hit `Esc` then `t` it will pop open NERDTree.

Comment: I'm running a Unix-y machine. I have NERDTree Installed, what I need is to have NERDTree to start when I type vim in the commandline. So that a file browser always opens to the left, like in Textmate. I don't know what to put into the vimrc to do this, I tried :NERDTree but it does not seem to recognise the command...

Comment: Thought I'd add that there is a :NERDTreeToggle built in mapping you can map to which makes your custom function rather redundant.

Comment: Excellent tip `alias vimt='vim -c "NERDTree" $1'`

Answer (score 9):

Per the [NERDTree instructions](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree#the-nerdtree) you can just use [pathogen.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen). Install it with:

```
mkdir -p ~/.vim/autoload ~/.vim/bundle; \
curl -Sso ~/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim \
        https://raw.github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen/master/autoload/pathogen.vim
```

Add this to your .vimrc:

```
execute pathogen#infect()
```

then install NERDTree:

```
cd ~/.vim/bundle
git clone https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree.git
```

And if you want to open a NERDTree automatically when Vim starts up, add the following to your .vimrc:

```
autocmd vimenter * NERDTree
```

Answer (score 7):

The answers here have a minor problem.

If you call `vim --noplugin` or use a script that uses `--noplugin` mode such as [vimpager](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1723), it will cause this error:

```
Error detected while processing VimEnter Auto commands for "*":
E492: Not an editor command: NERDTree
```

To avoid this, put the command in `~/.vim/after/plugin/NERD_tree.vim` instead:

```
autocmd VimEnter * NERDTree
```

And it might also be a good idea to test that `NERDtree` is available as well, i.e.:

```
if exists("loaded_nerd_tree")
    autocmd VimEnter * NERDTree
endif
```

Comment: Good One ... I also use Vim as a pager and simply added an argument to disable autocommands ...    
     
    `export MANPAGER='col -bx | mvim -c ":set ft=man nonu nolist" -c ":autocmd!" -M -R - > /dev/null 2>&1'`

Answer (score 7):

```
" NERD Tree
nmap <silent> <special> <F2> :NERDTreeToggle<RETURN>
```