# How to start VIM with NERD tree opened automatically?

Tags: vim, vi, nerdtree

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Auto-open NERDTree in “EVERY” tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979520/auto-open-nerdtree-in-every-tab)

Is there a way to automatically execute the `:NERDTree` command when VIM is launched for the first time or configure NERDTree to always open on startup?

PLEASE CLOSE. Just noticed that this question was answered before:
[Auto-open NERDTree in "EVERY" tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979520/auto-open-nerdtree-in-every-tab)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Yes. Just write this line to your .vimrc :

```
autocmd VimEnter * NERDTree
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me

Comment: @droope: do you have the NERDTree plugin installed?

Comment: hi @benoit, in the end i solved it with this :) many thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979520/auto-open-nerdtree-in-every-tab/7640505#7640505

Comment: `autocmd VimEnter * NERDTree`

Comment: @MostafaShahverdy's answer worked for me, Benoit's didn't

Comment: if you don't want to have to switch focus every time: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1448637/2397253