# can't open NERDTree

Tags: nerdtree

In my vimrc,

```
autocmd VimEnter * NERDTree
autocmd VimEnter * wincmd p
```

but when I start writting a file, it tips error:

```
  Error detected while processing VimEnter Auto commands for "*":
  E492: Not an editor command: NERDTree
```

Anyone can help me ?

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/a/5763243/72321

Answer (score 1):

I tried to install NERDTree using [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug), so when I started vim and run :PlugInstall, I can use :NERDTree command but after going out it was no available, reason is I didn't download plugin cause I used github, so according to [documentation](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug#example) you have to use it on demand and wrap it up your instruction:

```
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged') " Specify folder
Plug 'scrooloose/nerdtree', { 'on':  'NERDTreeToggle' }
call plug#end() " Initializes plugins
```

So your plugins are available now, and you can use your instructions:

```
autocmd VimEnter * NERDTree
autocmd VimEnter * wincmd p
```