# How to select what NERDTree window Vim focuses on depending whether a file is passed

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I currently have the following in my .vimrc:

```
au VimEnter * NERDTree
au BufWinEnter * NERDTreeMirror
```

This I believe launches NERDTree when I open Vim, as well as when I open a new tab using a plugin. Currently, when I launch Vim using

```
vim
```

at the command line, the cursor is sitting in NERDTree ready for me to navigate my files, which is great. However, when I use

```
vim my-file.txt
```

the cursor remains in the NERDTree window. I'm aware that I can add this to my .vimrc:

```
au BufNew * wincmd l
```

But that means the cursor will always be placed in the window to the right of NERDTree, even if I don't specify a file.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the command conditional on whether arguments were passed to Vim:

```
:au VimEnter * if argc() > 0 | wincmd l | endif
```

(I'd use the `VimEnter` event for that; just make sure this autocmd comes after the one that opens NERDTree.)

PS: There are a couple of related questions here:

- [Auto-open NERDTree in "EVERY" tab](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1979520/813602)
- [How do you add NERDTree to your vimrc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1447334/813602)